# read txt file in matlab and generate a 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, tf-idf

The problem is there are some group like auto,business etc and some words in these groups like car,gun etc in a txt file,'text.txt'

> sub.autos       $tab$    shift clutch car gear clutch car turn advanc repli
>       sub.autos         $tab$    bike long clutch pulsar
>       talk.politics.gun $tab$    assault AK-47 war assault
>       talk.politics.gun $tab$    country war terror

and I need to create TF-IDF ( term frequency – inverse document frequency), that is, number of times  a word occurs in a particular group in a form of a matrix in which each row will correspond to a group, and each column represents the occurrence of a particular word in respective group.

I know the method for txt file to 1-d array using textread but change it in 2-d made me clueless.i am a beginner in matlab and any help would be appreciated.

PS - tf-idf wiki link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf-idf

Comment: Hi, read the documentation of `textscan()`, `unique()`, and `histc()` and come back with some code examples of what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the section on using parameters with textread(). One of the parameters is 'whitesapce' that can be set to '/n'.

For example given the following data.txt file

```
Sally Level1
12.34 45 Yes
```

Using the code

```
[names, types] = textread('data.txt', '%s %s', 1, 'whitespace', '\n')
```

Returns

```
names = 'Sally Level1'
types = '12.34 45 YES'
```

I am no expert with using textread, but I hope this gives you something you can use.